# How to match all ASCII characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to remove all the non ASCII characters from a string and I have written following code but it is not able to find the new line character. When it is encountering the new line then it is replacing the encountered new line with a space character

string=string.replace(/[^\x00f-\x7f]/g,'');

Comment: In JavaScript, hex escapes in strings are in the form of backslash-x-hexdigit-hexdigit. You seem to be mangling the characters forming the range of your regex. I don't see how that would have the undesired result you describe, though.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is in range of 0 to 127, so use `/[^\x00-\x7F]/`

```js
var str="INFO] :谷���新道, ひば���ヶ丘２丁���, ひばりヶ���, 東久留米市 (Yo thats cool)";
str = str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
alert(str);
```